# Change Tax text to VAT in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

I want all 'Tax' changed with 'VAT' in the product and categorie page? but I can't find the file(s) to change it in.
Does anyone know witch css file the translation is and in witch file the are called?

**Solved** :  without languagepack for en_GB the overwrite voor en_GB isn't working. After installing languagepack the overwrite's works.

Comment: You can add "TAX" to "VAT" direct in language translation file, it will affect in whole site.

Comment: Thanks, but which file you referring to? I made changes to 6 files but not any result

Comment: app/design/frontend/{themepackage}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: If your site is multi store then add translation in whole store.

Comment: Can you be clear? What do I put in de en_GB.csv file ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a theme in `app/design/frontend/{themepackage}/{themename}/i18n/`, you can create a new translation dictionary as follows:

- Create the dictionary in the i18n folder and name it after the ISO language code you are translating to, i.e. To add a translation dictionary for German, add de_DE.csv to the i18n folder.
- Inside de_DE.csv, add your translation string as follows:
  "", ""
  "Shopping Cart", "Warenkorb"

Now, wherever you want Magento to translate a phrase, use the double-underscore translation method:
`<?php echo __('Shopping Cart'); ?>`

...and Magento 2 will search for the string 'Shopping Cart' in all translation dictionaries and replace it with whatever was defined in the dictionary, e.g. 'Warenkorb' in this example.

**Sources:**
Here is an introduction to translations in Magento 2: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Here is how to add translations to themes in Magento 2: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

Comment: Thanks, that I all knowing. The question is only how I can change Tax to VAT in the category and detail page. That I can't find!!

Comment: @MaartenV1 Then I would override the template for the part of the product/category page which has the translation phrase you want to change. That's the only way I can think of to use specific instances of a translation phrase.

Comment: i totale agre, that exact what I want, but......I can't find the file or the phrase I must translate....

Comment: @MaartenV1 Have you tried enabling template hints and refreshing the page? How about grep'ping the codebase? Or using your IDE's find text in files feature?

Comment: solved
without languagepack for en_GB the overwrite voor en_GB isn't working. After installing languagepack the overwrite's works.